# Permission denied while trying to delete even when delete is granted

Tags: postgresql, permissions

I recently had this issue where I created a database user and gave delete and update permission. Yet, I was getting permission denied on a delete query.

Create user: `create user username password 'whatever';`

Grant: `grant update, delete on table to username;`

Query which gave permission denied:

```
delete from table
where condition1 and
condition2 and
condition3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a bit of hunting I realized that maybe I am getting this error because I am adding a condition to delete. Which means the database is probably selecting those records. And I hadn't granted select on the table to the user.

Grant select: `grant select on table to username`

And it worked.